# 2-way Data Sync Between 2 Different Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to figure out how to create a sheet where I can have the status of an item shared between two sheets. If someone changes the status on the [source sheet (sheet 1)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wIA5tz7U2D6Ba1j_uLKu3alMhe1BrfT2r_ATY4FHp5c/edit#gid=1126662165), I want it to change the status on the [destination sheet (sheet 2)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qjx1oiKLBnjs4RcDn6MJ2E99F11zDomYd7972qmLUJs/edit#gid=1126662165) and vice versa.

Use Case: I don't want to share every sheet on the source sheet with a contractor and I want to be notified when they flip items to the next stage so I can review on the source sheet. I would love to be able to send work back to them when it doesn't meet QA standards.

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To create a setup where the status of an item is shared between two sheets and changes in one sheet are reflected in the other, you can use the following steps in Google Sheets:

A. Open a new Google Sheets document and create two sheets. Rename the first sheet as "Sheet 1" (source sheet) and the second sheet as "Sheet 2" (destination sheet).

B. In both sheets, create a column to represent the items and a column to represent the status. For example, in column A, you can list the items, and in column B, you can set the status.

C. In Sheet 1, select the range of cells in column B where you will be entering the status. Right-click on the selected range, choose "Data validation," and set up a validation rule to limit the status options to a predefined list (e.g., "To Do," "In Progress," "Completed"). This step ensures consistent status values across both sheets.

D. In Sheet 2, go to the cell in column B that corresponds to the first item. Enter the following formula:

```
   =Sheet1!B2
```

This formula pulls the status value from Sheet 1 and displays it in Sheet 2.

E. Copy the formula from the cell in step 4 and paste it into the remaining cells in column B of Sheet 2, corresponding to each item. The formula will adjust automatically for each row, fetching the status from Sheet 1.

F. Now, whenever you update the status of an item in Sheet 1, the corresponding cell in Sheet 2 will automatically update to reflect the new status. Similarly, if you update the status in Sheet 2, it will be reflected in Sheet 1.

With this setup, you can share the destination sheet (Sheet 2) with your contractor, and any changes they make to the status will be reflected in the source sheet (Sheet 1). You can review the status changes in Sheet 1 and take appropriate actions when necessary.

Note: Both sheets should be in the same Google Sheets document for this setup to work.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I actually need it in 2 separate Google sheets, not just another tab. Otherwise, the contractor could see and edit items in other tabs.

Comment: You could use google's permission structure to block access to other sheets if the account who accesses it has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: otherwise you can also specify the URL of an external document with relevant permissions like: `=IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE_SHEET_URL", "Sheet1!B2")`

Comment: Your last three answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you pretend to be able to modify the same cell from two different sheets and sync 2-way, it's not possible without code.

But, if you keep separate columns you can use IMPORTRANGE. Let's say you update the status in A column in the source sheet and consult B column with IMPORTRANGE from the other sheet. Then in destination sheet the contractor updates column B, and sees what you update in column A via IMPORTRANGE.

If that's the case, you'll get it running soon enough!